# Connecting dockerized Spring boot app to external MQTT server

Tags: spring, docker, docker-compose, containers, mqtt

I have a spring application acting as a mqtt client, whose server is installed on the machine as a windows service.

This is the connection string `tcp://localhost:1883`

In local everything works, the problem is when i try to dockerize the application. I also tried replacing *localhost* with *host.docker.internal*, but I still get the same error:
*org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttException: Unable to connect to server*

Thanks

This is the section of my docker-compose:

```
  mqtt:
    build:
      context: MQTT
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/mt_db
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: root
      mqttUrl: tcp://host.docker.internal:1883
    ports:
      - 8082:8082
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    networks:
      - my-network
```

The broker logs (Mosquitto on the host) contain:

```
1690385767: mosquitto version 2.0.15 starting 
1690385767: Config loaded from C:\Program Files\mosquitto/mosquitto.conf. 
1690385767: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883. 
1690385767: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883. 
1690385767: mosquitto version 2.0.15 running
```

This is my mosquitto.conf:

```
listener 1883
log_dest file C:\Users\andrea.palermo\Desktop\mosquitto.log
log_type all
```

This is the startup error:

```
mqtt_1        | org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttException: Unable to connect to server
mqtt_1        |         at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.TCPNetworkModule.start(TCPNetworkModule.java:80) ~[org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.2.5.jar!/:na]
mqtt_1        |         at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:724) ~[org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.2.5.jar!/:na]
mqtt_1        |         at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
mqtt_1        | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
mqtt_1        |         at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
mqtt_1        |         at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:412) ~[na:na]
mqtt_1        |         at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:255) ~[na:na]
mqtt_1        |         at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:237) ~[na:na]
mqtt_1        |         at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:na]
mqtt_1        |         at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609) ~[na:na]
mqtt_1        |         at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.TCPNetworkModule.start(TCPNetworkModule.java:74) ~[org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.2.5.jar!/:na]
mqtt_1        |         ... 2 common frames omitted
```

This when I try to do the publish

```
mqtt_1        | org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [bean 'mqttOutbound'; defined in: 'class path resource [it/mqtt/mqttmanagement/beans/MqttBeans.class]'; from source: 'it.mqtt.mqttmanagement.beans.MqttBeans.mqttOutbound()']; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to connect; nested exception is Unable to connect to server (32103) - java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused), failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload={"id_boat":"AAA","latitude":37,"longitude":15}, headers={replyChannel=nullChannel, id=aef51eec-4161-edd5-3c78-9c9df956ca9d, mqtt_topic=info/test, timestamp=1690443018860}]
mqtt_1        |         at org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.wrapInHandlingExceptionIfNecessary(IntegrationUtils.java:191)
mqtt_1        |         at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:64)
mqtt_1        |         at org.springframework.integration.handler.ReplyProducingMessageHandlerWrapper.handleRequestMessage(ReplyProducingMessageHandlerWrapper.java:59)
mqtt_1        |         at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:136)
mqtt_1        |         at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:55)
mqtt_1        |         at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
mqtt_1        |         at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
mqtt_1        |         at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
mqtt_1        |         at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
mqtt_1        |         at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:317)
mqtt_1        |         at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:272)
mqtt_1        |         at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
mqtt_1        |         at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
mqtt_1        |         at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
mqtt_1        |         at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
mqtt_1        |         at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.convertAndSend(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:151)
mqtt_1        |         at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.convertAndSend(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:143)
mqtt_1        |         at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.send(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:428)
mqtt_1        |         at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.sendOrSendAndReceive(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:657)
mqtt_1        |         at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invokeGatewayMethod(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:589)
mqtt_1        |         at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.doInvoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:556)
mqtt_1        |         at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:545)
mqtt_1        |         at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
mqtt_1        |         at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:220)
mqtt_1        |         at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy121.senToMqtt(Unknown Source)
mqtt_1        |         at it.mqtt.mqttmanagement.controller.MqttController.publishOtherBoats(MqttController.java:59)
mqtt_1        |         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
mqtt_1        |         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
mqtt_1        |         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
mqtt_1        |         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
mqtt_1        |         at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84)
mqtt_1        |         at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
mqtt_1        |         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
mqtt_1        |         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
mqtt_1        |         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
mqtt_1        |         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
mqtt_1        |         at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
mqtt_1        |         at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
mqtt_1        | Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to connect; nested exception is Unable to connect to server (32103) - java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
mqtt_1        |         at org.springframework.integration.mqtt.outbound.MqttPahoMessageHandler.checkConnection(MqttPahoMessageHandler.java:227)
mqtt_1        |         at org.springframework.integration.mqtt.outbound.MqttPahoMessageHandler.publish(MqttPahoMessageHandler.java:237)
mqtt_1        |         at org.springframework.integration.mqtt.outbound.AbstractMqttMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractMqttMessageHandler.java:269)
mqtt_1        |         at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:55)
mqtt_1        |         ... 36 more
mqtt_1        | Caused by: Unable to connect to server (32103) - java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
mqtt_1        |         at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.TCPNetworkModule.start(TCPNetworkModule.java:80)
mqtt_1        |         at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:724)
mqtt_1        |         ... 1 more
mqtt_1        | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
mqtt_1        |         at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
mqtt_1        |         at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:412)
mqtt_1        |         at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:255)
mqtt_1        |         at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:237)
mqtt_1        |         at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
mqtt_1        |         at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
mqtt_1        |         at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.TCPNetworkModule.start(TCPNetworkModule.java:74)
mqtt_1        |         ... 2 more
```

Comment: What server are you using? Check that it's not listening on `localhost` (the default for mosquitto) because with that configuration it will only accept local connections (and connections from a container are not local). You will need to connect to use `tcp://host.docker.internal:1883` and, if using mosquitto, add `listener 1883` to the config.

Comment: The server used is mosquitto. I added listener 1883 but keep getting the same error

Comment: Please run `netstat -aof | findstr :1883` on the host and then edit your question, adding the output.

Comment: This is the output: TCP 0.0.0.0:1883 nome_client:0 LISTENING 5096

Comment: Cool it looks like Mosquitto is using the config. Can you please enable logging (see `log_dest ` and `log_type` [here](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html)). The aim is to see if anything is logged when your application attempts to connect.

Comment: This is the content of the file:

"1690385767: mosquitto version 2.0.15 starting
1690385767: Config loaded from C:\Program Files\mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
1690385767: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
1690385767: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1690385767: mosquitto version 2.0.15 running"

Comment: Can you please confirm which `log_type` you have set? (ideally use `all` as this will log everything, meaning you will see any connection attempts). Assuming that you were using `all` it looks like no TCP connection is being established. Generally the exception will contain more info that you have posted; can you please edit the question and provide the complete message? (alternatively look into [logging](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Paho/Log_and_Debug_in_the_Java_client))

Comment: I updated with my mosquitto.conf (log_type all) and the errors

Comment: OK so based on `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)` it looks like the name is resolving but the connection is not getting through. Lets eliminate java - start up a mosquitto container (for the tools) with something like `docker run -it eclipse-mosquitto /bin/sh` then try and connect e.g. `mosquitto_pub -h host.docker.internal -t test -m test`.

Comment: Return this message: 
Connection error: Connection Refused: not authorised.
Error: The connection was refused.

Comment: Ok, so TCP connection is successful (unsurprising the brocker rejects the connection if you have not enabled anonymous connections). You should see activity in the mosquito log. So the issue appears to be with your Java app or something in the docker config you have not shown us.